# Keeping images inside of boxes when responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my picture stay inside of the grey box that I have it in. However, every time I am try and resize the browser the picture pops out of that area. If anyone has any ideas  . I wanted to add a Jsfiddle but since it has to do with pictures it doesn't show up and wouldn't help. Sorry about that... how I can keep the picture inside of that box that would really help. Thanks.

Here's a picture of the issue:-
[image]

```css
    .imgbox2{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    }

    #primary{
 background-color:#5E5757;
 color: white;
    }

    section{
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    }

     img{
    float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<section>
       
       <div id="box">
    <h1> GCOM 366</h1>
       <section class="clearfix" id="primary">
       <div class="imgbox2">
        <img class="adjustable" src="RDesign3.jpg" alt="example web page" width="300" heigh="300" >
        </div>
       <h2> Benefits</h2>
       
       <p class="side">
       1. Learn industry standard programs
       <br>
    2. Build Portfolio
    <br>
    3. Increase collaboration skills
    <br>
    4. Become more creative 
    <br>
    5. Understand good layout
    <br>
    6. Feel confident in HTML/CSS
    </p>
       </section>
```

Comment: Please check this link:-https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-responsive-centered-image/

Comment: You can add the image as a background. Add `background-size: contain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make images responsive, add this style for all images:

```
img {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

And you don't even need to float it and it will be nothing to clear then. Just add left, right margins to img parent container, in your case `.imgbox2` Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkaraliunas/n99rj9k9/

Comment: If you look at the demo you gave me the image is still falling out of the grey box on the right side. That is the issue that I am trying to fix, Thank you for trying to help! Do you have any other suggestions? @Giedrius

Comment: sorry, check this version: https://jsfiddle.net/gkaraliunas/n99rj9k9/2/

Comment: That looks perfect! THANK YOU! I will try it now and come back and tell you how it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help! It is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

add `width: calc(100% - 20px)` in image tag

```css
.imgbox2{
width:100%;
display:block;


}


#primary{
background-color:#5E5757;
color: white;
}

section{


width: 85%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;

margin-top: 35px;



}

 img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
```

```html
<section>

   <div id="box">
<h1> GCOM 366</h1>
   <section class="clearfix" id="primary">
   <div class="imgbox2">
    <img class="adjustable" src="RDesign3.jpg" alt="example web page" width="300" heigh="300" >
    </div>
   <h2> Benefits</h2>

   <p class="side">
   1.   Learn industry standard programs
   <br>
2.  Build Portfolio
<br>
3.  Increase collaboration skills
<br>
4. Become more creative 
<br>
5. Understand good layout
<br>
6. Feel confident in HTML/CSS
</p>
   </section>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. But thanks for trying to help me! I appreciate it! @jafarbtech

Comment: i have updated the answer. please check once again. what is the problem that you are still getting?

Comment: My image is still popping out of the grey box that I want it in when resizing the browser. Currently, I am trying to put it into a container and I'll see how that works @jafarbtech

Comment: please remove the `float:left`

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the inline width and height attributes from your image:

```
    <img class="adjustable" src="RDesign3.jpg" alt="example web page" width="300" heigh="300" >
```

So its just:

```
<img class="adjustable" src="RDesign3.jpg" alt="example web page">
```

Then in your stylesheet you can set a width of 100%, and a max-width of 300px...

```
.adjustable
{
    width:100%;
    max-width:300px;
}
```